# Using classes (not class components) in react to improve design architecture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-native, design-patterns

I have been using React for a few months now and am diving deeper in to application structure and design patterns. Of particular interest to me is handling multiple asynchronous calls that may depend on each other, dependant on the logic of user journeys.

I am currently building an app where I have multiple asynchronous operations that include using local storage, connecting and querying Firebase for phone number authentication and also a WebRTC React Native video calling platform.

In trying to figure out how to handle data received from these apis, I have come across a few examples of code where the authors are using plain classes, not class components to help build their application. My question is, what is this design pattern called and how should I approach using it? What are the best resources to read about its use?

For example, with Firebase phone number authentication a developer I found on Github writes this:

```
class FirebaseService {
    user = ''
    uid = ''
    userStatusDatabaseRef = ''
    userStatusFirestoreRef = ''

    constructor() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                const { uid, phoneNumber} = firebase.auth().currentUser._user
                UserStore.user.setUID(uid)
                UserStore.user.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                let ref = firebase.database().ref(`/Users/${UserStore.user.uid}`)
                ref.on('value', this.gotUserData)
            }
            this.setListenConnection()

        })
    }

    confirmPhone = async (phoneNumber) => {
        const phoneWithAreaCode = phoneNumber.replace(/^0+/,'+972'); 

        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            firebase.auth().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneWithAreaCode)
                .on('state_changed', async (phoneAuthSnapshot) => {
                    switch (phoneAuthSnapshot.state) {
                    case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFIED:
                        await this.confirmCode(phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId, phoneAuthSnapshot.code, phoneAuthSnapshot)
                        res(phoneAuthSnapshot)

                        break

                    case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.CODE_SENT:
                        UserStore.setVerificationId(phoneAuthSnapshot.verificationId)
                        res(phoneAuthSnapshot)
                        break
.......
```

Here he creates `FirebaseService` and there is also `UserStore` referenced. However, I just have a `FirebaseService.js` file, and pass in a callback to it `authorizeWithToken` from my container component to store a result to state via Redux in the component.

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

export const authorizeFirebase = (phoneNumber, authorizeWithToken) => {
  try {
    firebase.auth()
      .verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      .on('state_changed', (phoneAuthSnapshot) => {
        // console.log(phoneAuthSnapshot);
        switch (phoneAuthSnapshot.state) {
          case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.CODE_SENT: // or 'sent'
            console.log('code sent');
            break;
          case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.ERROR: // or 'error'
            console.log('verification error');
            console.log(phoneAuthSnapshot.error);
            break;
          case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFY_TIMEOUT: // or 'timeout'
            console.log('auto verify on android timed out');
            break;


          // '-------------------------------------------------------------'
          case firebase.auth.PhoneAuthState.AUTO_VERIFIED: // or 'verified'
            console.log('auto verified on android');
            const { verificationId, code } = phoneAuthSnapshot;
            const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code);
            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then(result => {
              const user = result.user;
              user.getIdToken().then(accessToken => {
                authorizeWithToken(accessToken);
```

My service is a function, and his is a class, neither of them are components.

To give another example - here is a class 'service' from a code example that is provided by video messaging platform ConnectyCube that I'm using:

```
import ConnectyCube from 'connectycube-reactnative'

class ChatService {
    // Chat - Core
    connect(user) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (!user) reject()

            ConnectyCube.chat.connect(
                {
                    userId: user.id,
                    password: user.password,
                },
                (error, contacts) => {
                    if (!error && contacts) {
                        resolve(contacts)
                    } else {
                        reject(error)
                    }
                },
            )
        })
    }

    disonnect() {
        ConnectyCube.chat.disconnect()
    }
}

// create instance
const Chat = new ChatService()

// lock instance
Object.freeze(Chat)

export default Chat
```

I haven't come across classes as services until now but I would really like to know how I should use them and what patterns I should follow. They look super useful and at the moment I have a spaghetti junction of local state, Redux and services that are connected via callbacks and complex `async await` setups. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just separate concerns, leave React to do what React is supposed to do which is managing the views of your app. Tailor your boundary interfaces to get the exact info required (and nothing else) from and into your other abstractions.

Comment: @MinusFour thanks and understood, but when should I store data in Redux and when should I update a class instance properties? So for example, should I store a users phone number in a `User` class instance or in the Redux store?

Comment: If the phone number is relevant to the state of your app then yes it should be on your Redux store, if it's only relevant to your User class then no.

Comment: Ok understood - thanks. What about if I'm taking a functional approach to building the app / components. Is using classes in this way still relevant / used?

Comment: Probably there are no diffs, but I prefer to use class component instead of function component because I have more control, e.g. I can put some debug info inside a class 'constructor' and see when it's created.